# Dragging layout doesn't work in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an empty xml file, and I want to drag a ConstraintLayout in the Design tab, but it won't work:

[image]

Comment: Have u added `dependencies` of constraint-layout `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'`

Comment: Yes, in fact dragging any other layout won't work, not only ConstraintLayout, it was just an example

Comment: Its look like have issu with the main layout, have you any warning in xml? What is the main layout? He is draw with '?' on the left

Answer (score 1):

I think your layout.xml in text pane is empty. You just put one linearlayout or whatever layout that suit you inside it with below tag

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

then you will be able to drag widget inside design pane

Comment: thank you, it is empty, I just thought that if a Layout is in the draggable menu, than I could just drag a layout even if the text part is empty. Not a big deal, just thought it would be nice if I could also drag a layout rather than typing it

Comment: When you are creating layout in resource layout file you choose the root element and it is impossible to create layout file with empty tag unless you clear it manually.